# core_url_rewrite missing

Tags: magento-1.9, database

So I just started to manage, not really develop, a Magento 1.9 for a new employer. With my previous employer we made certain anyone creating new products, via duplicating existing, wiped out the url key field as to not create duplicate keys. this company has not done that so the url rewrites are about 500 points above the product id value in the url path and growing with each reindex. So i figure the `core_url_rewrite` table must be huge.... but the `core_url_rewrite` table is not even in the database..

So where would it be writing them to? Is there another place to look? Did a patch delete the table?

`System>Config>Web>SEO>Use Web Server Rewrites` is set to yes

Please advise and thanks for the help and guidance

ps. I don't understand shell scripts via ssh yet so that is not gonna happen ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe using Magento EE? In that case the table is named `enterprise_url_rewrite` but I think the `core_url_rewrite` should be nevertheless there.